# why grep with regex command not working on Ubuntu

Tags: grep, regex

I wanted to know the packages which are installed and starting with mos then below command not working.

```
dpkg -l | grep  ^mos*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `^mos*` is a perfectly cromulent grep Basic regular Expression (BRE), it likely doesn't mean what you think it means. **You should also get into the habit of quoting any pattern that you pass to grep, so that the shell does not try to expand it to a list of filenames in the current directory.**<sup>1</sup>

`*` in a regular expression is a *quantifier* rather than a wildcard, so `mos*` means `m` `o` then zero or more `s` characters. The regex equivalent of the shell wildcard `*` would be `.*` (any character, zero or more times). However since grep by default outputs the whole line even when the match is partial, a trailing `.*` is superfluous - `^mos` would do as well as `^mos.*`

However `^` anchors a regular expression to the start of a *line* - and `dpkg -l` outputs the package's status before its name, so `^mos` will never match in this context.

You could use `^..  *mos` to match two arbitrary status characters anchored to start-of-line, followed by one or more spaces before `mos`:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep '^..  *mos'
ii  most                                      5.0.0a-4                                       amd64        Pager program similar to more and less
```

however I'd suggest using awk instead of grep for this task, since you can match against specific *fields* ex.

```
$ dpkg -l | awk '$2 ~ /^mos/'
ii  most                                      5.0.0a-4                                      amd64        Pager program similar to more and less
```

or if you want to output only matching installed packages for example

```
dpkg -l | awk '$1 == "ii" && $2 ~ /^mos/'
```

---

1. or at least to stop relying on the shell to pass the literal value of the pattern to grep when it does *not* match - although bash does so by default, other shells (zsh in particular) don't.

Answer (score 2):

To get `grep` use regex add `-E` switch this way:

```
dpkg -l | grep -E '^mos.*'
```

But this won't give you any results, because `dpkg -l` lines start with `ii` and other chars.

You can try this one:

```
apt list --installed | grep -E '^mos.*'
```